# Trouble making a running sum in Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm stuck trying to get a running sum to work in an Access query.
I've been playing around with various Dsum expressions, but they all have resulted in errors.
Basically, I have two columns, one with a year, one with a count of parts for that year, and I would like the third to be a running sum of the part count over the years.

My SQL for the first two columns looks like this:

```
    SELECT DatePart("yyyy",[EoL]) AS AYear, Count(EquipmentQuery.Equipment) AS EquipCount
    FROM EquipmentQuery
    GROUP BY DatePart("yyyy",[EoL])
    ORDER BY DatePart("yyyy",[EoL]);
```

Any suggestions on how to get the third column to work as a running sum?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a report, there is a [property to calculate a running sum](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/calculate-a-running-sum-cumulative-total-HP005187388.aspx).

If you prefer a query, you can use a subquery to calculate the running sum:

```
SELECT  DatePart("yyyy",[EoL]) AS AYear
,       Count(eq1.Equipment) AS EquipCount
,       (
        SELECT  Count(eq2.Equipment)
        FROM    EquipmentQuery eq2
        WHERE   DatePart("yyyy",eq2.[EoL]) <= DatePart("yyyy",eq1.[EoL])
        ) AS RunningSuma
FROM    EquipmentQuery AS eq1
GROUP BY 
        DatePart("yyyy",[EoL])
ORDER BY 
        DatePart("yyyy",[EoL]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
SELECT Year([EQ1].[EOL]) AS Yr, 
Sum(IIf(Year([EQ2].[eol])=Year([EQ1].[eol]),1,0)) AS [current], 
Sum(IIf(Year([EQ2].[eol])<=Year([EQ1].[eol]),1,0)) AS [cumulative]
FROM [equipmentquery] AS EQ1, [equipmentquery] AS [EQ2]
GROUP BY Year([EQ1].[EOL]);
```

ansd if you want running totals instead of counts:

```
SELECT Year([EQ1].[EOL]) AS Yr, 
Sum(IIf(Year([EQ2].[eol])=Year([EQ1].[eol]),[EQ2].equipment,0)) AS [current], 
Sum(IIf(Year([EQ2].[eol])<=Year([EQ1].[eol]),[EQ2].equipment,0)) AS [cumulative]
FROM [equipmentquery] AS EQ1, [equipmentquery] AS [EQ2]
GROUP BY Year([EQ1].[EOL]);
```