# Access 2013 Query Running Total by 2 Columns

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Access 2013 Query Running Total by 2 Columns

### I have a table with following details:-

```
Class  Division  Count
1       A         10
1       B         10
1       C         10
2       A         20
2       B         20
2       C         20
```

Need to create a query with output as shown below:-

```
Class  Division  Count RunTotal
1       A         10    10
1       B         10    20
1       C         10    30
2       A         20    20
2       B         20    40
2       C         20    60
```

Notice that Runtotal is cumulative by both CLASS and DIVISION.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble making a running sum in Access query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347778/trouble-making-a-running-sum-in-access-query)

Comment: This has running total only by one column i,e. year.

Comment: The principle is still the same. Once you understand how the linked solution works, solving your problem is a natural extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can creating a running sum like so:

```
SELECT tx.Class, tx.Division, tx.Count, 
  (SELECT Sum([Count]) 
   FROM MyTable t WHERE t.Class=tx.Class 
   AND t.Division<=tx.Division) AS Running
FROM MyTable tx
ORDER BY tx.Class, tx.Division;
```

Result:

```
Class   Division    Count   Running
1       A           10      10
1       B           10      20
1       C           10      30
2       A           20      20
2       B           20      40
2       C           20      60
```

Comment: This is giving cumulative result but i don't get one record by Class and Division. So I get 10 records for 1 / A / 10 / 10  and then 20 records for 1 / B / 10 / 20..    When I try to add Group by Class and Division, I get error "You query does not include the specified expression 'Count' as part of aggregate function"..

Comment: For me, it gives exactly the result you requested with the information you provided.

Comment: Will it make a difference if MyTable is a Query instead of table? Because I checked you query with mine and its exactly same and I dont knw why it shows output as explained above comment :(

Comment: Your question is fairly short on information. If you want to include a field in an aggregate, it needs to be Sum, Group By or any other aggregate function. Yes, it can make a difference if you are using a query.

Comment: Ahh yes in my case MyTable is a query with data as shown in question. To aggregate I tried putting count on  <BR> SELECT tx.Class, tx.Division, COUNT(tx.Count), 
  (SELECT Sum([Count]) 
   FROM MyTable t WHERE t.Class=tx.Class 
   AND t.Division<=tx.Division) AS Running
FROM MyTable tx  GROUP BY tx.Class, tx.Division;
ORDER BY tx.Class, tx.Division;