# Importing Excel Formula to MS Access

Tags: excel, ms-access

Good day,

I'm importing data from a table in Excel to Access and I have a column that is calculated as such :

```
=SUM($E$2:E2)
```

To keep an aggregate of the data *up to that row* and not the grand total. So the first data row of the table will have the values of E2, second row will have E2 to E3, third row will have E2 to E4 and so on... Is there a way to replicate this in Access?

Thank you.

Comment: A database don't know about sorting the data records until you will set some order using `ORDER BY`. So first you will need a field which determine the order. Then you can do this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290136.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble making a running sum in Access query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347778/trouble-making-a-running-sum-in-access-query)