# MS Access Query - This has me stumped

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to write a query in Microsoft Access to summarize this data:

| Date | Description | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02/15/20 | Initial Fund Balance | 10000 |
| 06/21/20 | Fund Contribution | 2000 |
| 12/01/20 | Fund Appreciation | 5250 |
| 12/01/21 | Fund Appreciation | 5418 |
| 12/01/22 | Fund Appreciation | 5610 |
| 03/16/23 | Fund Contribution | 3500 |
| 12/01/23 | Fund Appreciation | 5814 |

```
Select year(Date) as MyDate, Sum(Amount) as FundBal 
from Tran 
Group by Year(Date)
```

This summarizes the activity for each year but does not include the activity from prior years.

I need a MS Access Query to Total the fund balance by year and return the following:

| Year | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 17250 |
| 2021 | 22668 |
| 2022 | 28278 |
| 2023 | 37592 |

Thanks in advance for any help.
Keith

Comment: You are asking for a _running sum_. Search on that, lot of examples.

Comment: Use a simple group by-clause based on year(date) and use Sum(amount)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble making a running sum in Access query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347778/trouble-making-a-running-sum-in-access-query)