# Sum of orders Based on Customer Name

Tags: ms-access

I have a problem with trying to generate a new query based on the total number of orders by customer.

I have tried going on the internet and found several solutions, but I can't seem to solve it.

I only require to access two columns which are from two different tables
The tblCustomers which has the Customer Name and the tblOrder Line Item which has the quantity

tblCustomer

> Customer ID, Customer Name, ... etc .. etc

And the following
tblOrder Line Item

> Order Number, Product ID, Quantity,...etc, ...etc

[image: Query and Database relationship]

[image: Query Result]

As you can see on the right, the total order should be sorted by customer. A running sum based on each customer name. I generally use the expression builder for most of the SQL queries.

I have tried using a DSUM, but it was on a specific table, however my customer name is in the tblCustomers whereas my quantity of orders are in the tblOrder Line Item.

The other method of using a running sum failed, unsuccessfully, as I can't seem to insert a nested Select query into my original query.

Does anyone know a method to solve this predicament.

//////Update/////

This is the Sql code

```
SELECT 
    tblCustomers.[Customer Name], 
    [tblOrder Line Item].[Order Number], 
    tblProducts.[Product Description], 
    [tblOrder Line Item].Size, 
    [tblOrder Line Item].Color, 
    tblProducts.Price, 
    [tblOrder Line Item].Quantity,
FROM 
    tblProducts 
INNER JOIN 
    ((tblCustomers INNER JOIN tblOrders ON tblCustomers.[Customer ID] = tblOrders.[Customer ID]) 
INNER JOIN 
    [tblOrder Line Item] ON tblOrders.[Order Number] = [tblOrder Line Item].[Order Number]) ON tblProducts.[Product ID] = [tblOrder Line Item].[Product ID]
GROUP BY 
    tblCustomers.[Customer Name], 
    [tblOrder Line Item].[Order Number], 
    tblProducts.[Product Description], 
    [tblOrder Line Item].Size, 
    [tblOrder Line Item].Color, 
    tblProducts.Price, 
    [tblOrder Line Item].Quantity;
```

I am trying to another select with 2 inner joins. But I can't seem to insert the code into the above SQL code.

This is the inner join I am thinking to add

```
(SELECT [Quantity] 
 FROM [tblOrder Line Item] c,  
 INNER JOIN [tblOrders] o on c.Order Number = o.Order Number 
 INNER JOIN [tblCustomers] a on o.Customer ID = a.Customer ID)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble making a running sum in Access query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347778/trouble-making-a-running-sum-in-access-query)

Comment: This is a common topic https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/create-a-running-totals-query. Provide sample data as text tables as well as attempted query SQL statement. Easiest approach is to build a report and use textbox RunningSum property.

Comment: If DSum() that requires data from two tables, then build a query object that joins queries. Reference that query in the DSum(). Don't need customer name to aggregate by customer. In fact, really should use Customer ID. Advise not to use spaces in naming convention.

Comment: Im afraid i need to have a calculated field, yea i understand the report has a sum function which is super handy. There is a standard method for a normal sql query i just need to select, quantity from tblorder line item c, and inner join tblOrders o on c.Ordernumber = o.Ordernumber Inner join tblcustomers a  on o.customer id = a.customer id ... i just need to find out how to insert it into the inner query.

Comment: You describe only 2 tables yet query references 4. Where do you want that additional SQL positioned? Save the second query then use Query Designer to add to the first. Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what running sum you mean but assuming a running sum of quantity as order number increases for each customer. We can use either Dlookup or a correlated subquery for the running sum.

First Foreign Keys are not Primary Keys.  You do not have to remove the space in the variable names.  I just couldn't get the sql with all the inner joins to work and thought the space might be the problem.

[image]

[image]

Working from qryCustomerOrderLineItems and using Dlookup for the running sum:

[image]

```
Total: Min(DSum("Quantity","qryCustomerOrderLineItems","OrderNumber<= " & [OrderNumber] & " AND CustomerID= " & [CustomerID]))
'to group by price or size just expand the where clause of the DSUM
'min, max, first, and last are equivalent for grouping 1 number
' in the totals row access changes summary functions like min to expression by moving them inside
```

You can also grab everything from qryCustomerLineItems and or use a correlated subquery for the running sum

[image]

```
Total: (SELECT Sum(Quantity) FROM [qryCustomerOrderLineItems] AS q WHERE q.OrderNumber <= [qryCustomerOrderLineItems].[OrderNumber]
AND q.CustomerID=[qryCustomerOrderLineItems].[CustomerID])
```

Both queries give the same result:

[image]