# Microsoft Access running sum in a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum

I am trying to make a running sum in Microsoft Access Query

Here is my table "T1", the order is the index field

```
Produkt Salgsdato   salg    Index  
A   01-02-2023  2   844  
B   02-02-2023  10  845  
C   03-02-2023  50  846  
D   04-02-2023  30  847  
E   05-02-2023  5   848  
F   06-02-2023  10  849
```

Now I want a running sum using this query

```
SELECT 
T1.Produkt, 
T1.salg, 
T1.Index, 
(Select Sum( T1.Salg ) From T1 as a2 where a2.Index <= T1.Index) AS total
FROM T1
ORDER BY T1.Index;
```

The result is the salg * rows ???

```
Produkt salg    Index   total     Should have been     Total is   
A   2   844 2               2                2 times 1 row  
B   10  845 20              12               10 times 2 rows  
C   50  846 150             62               50 times 3 rows  
D   30  847 120             92  
E   5   848 25              97  
F   10  849 60             107
```

It seems that it sums the salg * number of rows there is <= index

How to fix this?

Comment: This is very common. Search for "running sum". Also, note that a _report_ can do this for you natively.

Comment: Agree with Gustav. This is difficult in Access query but fairly simple with report where textbox has RunningSum property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble making a running sum in Access query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347778/trouble-making-a-running-sum-in-access-query)